# Eclipse shows no content assist context menu (popup box) for HTML files but works fine for Java files

Tags: html, eclipse, contextmenu, autosuggest, content-assist

I use Eclipse 2022-12 with Windows 10 for a Spring Boot project with Maven.

The context menu (the popup box that automatically shows up when you type or press Strg+Space) for autocompletion (java template proposals / content assist) in the editor shows up perfectly fine in Java files (strg + space works too).

I have HTML files that open with the HTML-editor in Eclipse, and the syntax highlighting is fine. But the context menu for code suggestions (auto completion suggestion or html template proposals) simply does not show up, not even with strg+space.

How can I enable the popup for the auto suggestions in HTML files again?

For clarification: It does not show the context menu box at all. Other users had problems where there were no suggestions (template proposals) inside the context menu, but for me the popup does not show up at all for HTML files, but for Java files it works completely fine.

I already tried to change the settings for the html editor under Window > Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor > Content Assist. Settings:
"Automatically make suggestions" - activated
"Auto activation delay" - 0
"Prompt when these characters are inserted" - "=<"
The categories for HTML Tag proposals and all the other elements are all activated in booth "Default Proposal Categories" and "Content Assist Pages".

I also de- and reinstalled Eclipse Web Developer Tools and HTML Editor in the Marketplace.

I also opened a new dynamic web project without Maven or Spring Boot, here the HTML editor also does not show the content assist context menu.

I also created a new Workspace, same result.

## Edit

I found a workaround...but this does not answer my question, because I think it is not correct that Eclipse does not show me the popup-box inside the HTML-Editor.

Eclipse automaticaly activated the HTML-Editor for HTML-Files, which does not have the popup-box. I activated the Generic Text Editor, which actually shows me the popup-box with HTML-suggestions. I would be happy if someone has a hint why the HTML-Editor is broken in Eclipse 2022-12.

Comment: You should not have the "HTML Editor (WTP)" Marketplace solution installed. It's pointing to version from 2016, and the submitter has never updated the solution. Are entries showing up in the Error Log when content assist fails to show up? How as this 2022-12 originally installed?

Comment: There are no entries showing up in the error log. I dont understand your second question there must be a typo I guess.

Comment: I found a workaround...but I am not marking my question as an answer, because I think it is not correct that Eclipse does not show me the popup-box inside the HTML-Editor.

Eclipse automaticaly activated the HTML-Editor for HTML-Files, which does not have the popup-box. I activated the Generic Text Editor, which actually shows me the popup-box with HTML-suggestions.

I would be happy if someone has a hint why the HTML-Editor is broken in Eclipse 2022-12.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. How was this 2022-12 originally installed? If it was an upgrade from a prior release, can you do a fresh installation?

Comment: I first had an older Eclipse version, then I upgraded it to 2022-12 - but only _after_ and because the popup box did not show up in the HTML-editor in the old version. :D I will try a fresh installation when I find the time. The error log also shows some errors. I confused it with the markers log. Most of the errors are about Mylyn FrameworkEvent errors.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings

> Window
> ⮑ Preferences
> ⮑ HTML Files
> ⮑  Editor
> ⮑  Content Assist

Then replace `<=` with;

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._<=
```

Comment: The path you are suggesting is for another eclipse version. In my Eclipse the HTML-Files section is in Window>Preferences>Web>HTML Files > Editor >Content Assist.

Replacing "<=" with your characters does not solve my problem.